# Cannot install any ruby gems on Mac OS - SSL_connect error

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl, rubygems

My environment is Mac OS 10.10.5, ruby version 2.2.4 (or 2.2.2 or 2.2.0) gem (after upgrade) is 2.6.7, rvm version 1.27.0.

This has several duplicates even in the last few days but this is more information than I can put in a comment.

When installing any gems on any version of ruby I get the following:

```
$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

There is a lot of information about this available, especially for problems on Windows. See http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/ for the proposed solution. I follow this but I continue to get the same error.

The problem seems to be in getting the file GlobalSignRootCA.pem in the appropriate place which is not entirely clear. The above link explains how to find the appropriate ssl_certs directory, of which there are 2 in my system, but neither work.

I forget where I learned the following:

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR'
/etc/openssl/certs
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

which might have given a hint but appending the .pem file to the latter or copying to the former have no effect.

When I re-install openssl (homebrew), it helpfully tells me:

```
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash
```

but this also does not solve the problem.

From another SO question:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

doesn't work. Nor does:

```
security find-certificate -a -p /Library/Keychains/System.keychain > "$cert_file"
security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain >> "$cert_file"
```

Does anyone know how to get a sense of what rubygems expects here? Where does it want this file or is this even the file it wants? Should I import the .pem file into the OSX keychain? How does one do that?

Or is there a way to get the gem file and install it locally? rubygems does this helpfully for rubygems itself but not for the individual gems from what I can tell.

-- workaround

Okay - the answer to the question of where to get the gem: go to `https://rubygems.org/gems/[package name]` and select a version and go to download - currently under links on the right hand side. Download the file and `gem install --local [downloaded gem file]`. Plus all the dependencies.

To automate:

```
# start by adding insecure source for --explain - thanks to @tnum
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
while read x 
do
wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/$x.gem
gem install --local $x.gem 
rm $x.gem
done < <(gem install --explain [package name] | grep "^  ")
# remove insecure source
gem source -r http://rubygems.org/
```

Some of the lack of security could be mitigated by a better grep regex but it is still insecure. Note that `wget https://` works so the ssl problem is definitely with rubygems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and used the following 'work around'-
cd into your rails app directory and run the following

```
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

This will use the insecure http connection rather than the secure https when you run the 'gem install...' command. It's not ideal but it is a short term work around.

You may also need to change the source line in your gemfile from

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: This sort of works. I installed bundler with just a warning - as expected. But when I install mongoid I get something that looks like someone's personal build. Thanks, this gives me a lot more options.

Comment: the mongoid thing is strange but irrelevant. But this helped me answer my second question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

According to https://rvm.io/support/fixing-broken-ssl-certificates, running command above will fix you issue :

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Comment: This actually works if you delete the appropriate cert.pem file first as is described in the link mentioned. Unfortunately osx-ssl-certs file simply sees the file and says it is already updated. If you follow the manual instructions in the link it works.

Answer (score 1):

@tnum's answer got me what I needed without security but I wanted to explain the problem.

I installed ruby 2.3.1 and and everything worked in that version. I tried to find out what the difference was and came up with this:

`ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'`

comes up with two answers. For 2.2.4 it seems to use its own directory `/etc/openssl/` but for 2.3.1 it uses `openssl version -d` which on my computer is `/etc/local/etc/openssl/`.

I copied the file cert.pem from the latter to the former and now gem works on ruby 2.2.4.

There are so many options for where these certificates might reside that this is way too confusing.