# Cocoapods unable to download data from ruby

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods

Im very new to Xcode and im trying to get firebase but cocoapods wont install. Whenever I type `gem install cocoapods` or `sudo gem install cocoapods` I get this...

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Im pretty sure I have the latest version of ruby (2.0.0), Xcode 8.2, and im running MacOS 10.11.6 El Capitan on a mid2007 IMac. Im not sure if my computer is outdated and cant download it.

I haven't found any clear answers anywhere else other than try putting sudo in front of gem so any help is appreciated. Sorry in advanced if this question has been asked or if its a very simple fix, I am very new to xcode and coding in general.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029184/cannot-install-any-ruby-gems-on-mac-os-ssl-connect-error) help you out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to leave this question up in case anyone else who is new wanted an easy answer. I also added this as a duplicate question to one with a more in depth answer I think.

How I fixed my problem:

I installed homebrew https://brew.sh/

Then I used homebrew to install rbenv with `brew install rbenv`

Once I had rbenv I downloaded 2.0.0-dev instead of 2.0.0 and used `rbenv local 2.0.0-dev` to set it as my main ruby version. 
Then I opened a new terminal and proceeded as normal by installing cocoapods and installing a podfile into my xcode.